# SELECT INNNER JOIN from friends and owner's posts

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 3 tables: user_info , friend_match, posts

user_info : **account_id** | **username**

friend_match : **friendship_id** | **friend1** (account_id of 1st) | **friend2** (account_id of 2nd) 
Friend match contains 2 1 and 1 2, 1 3 and 3 1.

posts : **post_id** | **poster_id** | **post_message** | **date_posted**

How would I get posts from the user's friends and his own ?

I have tried this, but it seems inefficient and I'm having issues with pagination because the users may have posted more or less which throw off the pagination.

```
SELECT * FROM 
                    (
                    SELECT p.post_id, p.post_message, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(p.date_posted) as date_posted, u.username FROM posts p
                    INNER JOIN friend_match fm
                        ON p.poster_id = fm.friend1
                    INNER JOIN user_info u
                        ON u.account_id = p.poster_id
                    WHERE fm.friend2 = $sessionid

UNION ALL

                    SELECT p.post_id, p.post_message, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(p.date_posted) as date_posted, u.username FROM posts p
                    INNER JOIN user_info u
                        ON u.account_id = p.poster_id
                    WHERE p.poster_id = $sessionid
                    )z
                    ORDER BY post_id DESC LIMIT $page,$limit";
```

My end result that I'm hoping for contains posts in order from newest to oldest with the friends posts intermingled with sessionholder's posts in a way that's reliably paginable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a full answer, but maybe use a [sub-select](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/any-in-some-subqueries.html) somehow like this:

```
SELECT * FROM posts p
  inner join user_info u ON u.account_id = p.poster_id
WHERE p.poster_id = $sessionid or p.poster_id IN 
(SELECT f.friend1 FROM friend_match f
 WHERE f.friend2 = $sessionid)
ORDER BY post_id DESC LIMIT $page, $limit;
```

Comment: Agh! I tried this method before and it said subquery returned multiple results, my syntax was wrong. You showed me the right way. Thank you! Works.